# If statement to only select certain XML attributes

Tags: python, xml

I'm attempting to get 2 different elements from an XML file; I'm trying to print them as the x and y on a scatter plot. I can manage to get both the elements but one list is 155 long and the other only 50.

So I need to add an `if` statement to just select `from` elements that have an associated `windSpeed` element.

```
url = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?lat=52.41616;lon=-4.064598"
response = requests.get(url)
xml_text=response.text
weather= bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml_text, "xml")
f = open('file.xml', "w")
f.write(weather.prettify())
f.close()
```

I'm then trying to get the time (`from`) element and the `(windSpeed > mps)` element and attribute. I'd like to use use Beautifulsoup if possible, or a straight `if` loop would be great.

```
with open ('file.xml') as file:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(file, "xml")
    times = soup.find_all("time")
    windspeed = soup.select("windSpeed")
    form = ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

    x = []
    y = []
    for element in times:
        time = element.get("from")
        t = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, form)
        x.append(t)

    for mps in windspeed:
        speed = mps.get("mps")
        y.append(speed)

    plt.scatter(x, y)         
    plt.show()
```

When I run it raises the following error:

```
raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

I'm assuming it's because the lists are different lengths.
I know there's probably a simple way of fixing it, any ideas would be great.

Comment: Rather than having a separate loop, can you check inside `for element in times:` if it has a `windspeed` element before adding the time item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your code snippet as follows. It will solve the length problem.

```
....
for element in times:
    time = element.get("from")
    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, form)
    if element.find('windSpeed'):
        x.append(t)
....
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what I needed, I knew I was missing something and I just couldn't figure it out.